# ASSERT(AfxGetThread() == NULL); fails

Tags: c++, mfc, assertions

I'm currently reworking an old project by replacing the menubar with a ribbon. I created a Frame etc. but I get assertion fail in appcore.cpp on this line:

ASSERT(AfxGetThread() == NULL);

From what I read recently, something must be wrong with the constructor.

May be it's good to point that I removed the Doc and View classes. But I read somewhere that it shouldn't be a problem :/
Help, anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Doc and View classes probably broke some underlying framework code.  You should probably start from scratch and use the app wizard to create the new framework you want, and, then port the "old" code over to it.

Comment: I think I replaced everything related to them. I sort of located the problem:
CWinAppEx m_waeApp;
m_waeApp.InitInstance(); //Here it breaks so I guess something's wrong with m_waeApp's constructor.
If I try CWinAppEx::InitInstance(); and continue debugging with F10 I end up here:
if ( !managedapp )
                exit(mainret); //in file crt0.c. It just exits with no errors :/

Comment: You are not allowed to call InitInstance by youself. It is called by the Framework when it starts.

Comment: But... I called it from a working example(created with the wizard) :/

Comment: I mean CWinAppEx::InitInstance(); Before that the other developer used CWinAppEx m_waeApp; m_waeApp.InitInstance(); and it was working until now o.O

Comment: I added a Doc and a View. Now I'm facing another problem, again an assertion:
CString strTitlePane1;
 CString strTitlePane2;
 bNameValid = strTitlePane1.LoadString(IDS_STATUS_PANE1);
 ASSERT(bNameValid);
 bNameValid = strTitlePane2.LoadString(IDS_STATUS_PANE2);
 ASSERT(bNameValid); //it breaks on the first assertion(I guess it would be the same with the second, if I just remove the first). Now, when I point the LoadString function, the tip is #define LoadString LoadStringA. In the working version a mentioned about, it's #define LoadString LoadStringW. Has this any connection to the problem?

Comment: I see it's related to whether UNICODE is defined or not. Does MFC only work with unicode?